# What is the largest $n$ for which the $n$th prime is known?

Tags: prime-numbers

$p = 2^{43,112,609} - 1$ is currently [the largest known prime](http://primes.utm.edu/largest.html#biggest), but the $n$ for which this $p$ is the $n$th prime is, presumably, unknown.  What is the largest $n$ for which the $n$th prime *is* known?  (For the sake of definiteness, let's say a number is "known" iff all of its decimal digits have been computed.)

Comment: Are you sure that all the decimal digits of $2^{43,112,609}-1$ were calculated? Seems like there are a lot of digits there. The sort of thing that would take quite some time.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila: Yes, they're even [online](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/math/prime/mersenne.html#M43112609).

Comment: @Asaf: You know *exactly* what this looks like in binary (a string of 43112609 ones), so finding the decimal digits should be *very* fast.

Comment: @cardinal, r.e.s: I see, thanks!

Comment: The prime pages [recommends](http://primes.utm.edu/notes/faq/LongestList.html) that one look at [Nicely's gap list](http://www.trnicely.net/gaps/gaplist.html).

Comment: @r.e.s.: I have wondered this question myself, though I also have wondered what _practical_ need there would be for this.

Comment: @DJC: I'm unaware of any practical use, and was merely curious whether $\pi(x)$ might somehow be known for $x$ roughly in the ballpark of the largest known prime (say $x$ with $10^7$ digits). I guess it might never happen, given that (1) currently-known values are for $x$ having at most about $24$ digits, and (2) the fastest known algorithms for $\pi(x)$ require times that grow exponentially in the number of digits of $x$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [this email](http://primes.utm.edu/notes/pi%2810%5E24%29.html), Jens Franke computed the [prime counting function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function) $\pi(n)$ for $n=10^{24}$, assuming the Riemann Hypothesis.  He found $\pi(10^{24})=18435599767349200867866$.

Using [Alpertron](http://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM) we can readily find the next primes:

- $10^{24}+7$ is the 18435599767349200867867-th prime.
- $10^{24}+49$ is the 18435599767349200867868-th prime.
- $10^{24}+121$ is the 18435599767349200867869-th prime.

These computations take less than 0.1 seconds to perform on my home computer (so it would take less than 0.1 seconds to beat these results).

Comment: Excellent. That seems to go well beyond the prime gap tables; and thanks for showing how quickly the next primes can be found -- essentially for as long as one has the time to continue. If the RH is *not* assumed, then I suppose $\pi(10^{23}) = 1925320391606803968923$ is the largest value of $\pi(10^n)$ so far computed (according to [this pdf document](http://wstein.org/projects/stueve.pdf), that took 2 CPU-months in 2006!). So even without RH, one finds $10^{23} + 117$ as the $(1925320391606803968923 + 117)$th prime, etc. etc.

Comment: I can't edit my previous comment, and someone has +1'd it, so let me just note the typo that should instead read as "the $(1925320391606803968923+\color{red}{1})$th prime, etc. etc."

Comment: "...plus oneth" is a rare rhyme for "month"

Answer (score 6):

update 2014:

$\begin{align}π(10^{26}) = 1699246750872437141327603\\
π(2^{89})= 1320486952377516565496055\end{align}$

Both culled from OEIS, http://oeis.org/A006880, http://oeis.org/A007053. A likely source for reasonably up to date info on this kind of thing.

Comment: OEIS currently giving $\pi\left(10^{29}\right)=1520698109714272166094258063$ and the rather smaller  $\pi\left(2^{92}\right)= 78908656317357166866404346$ so it would not surprise me if the latter was out of date

Answer (score 2):

See the discussion [here](http://primes.utm.edu/notes/faq/LongestList.html). Among other things, it says "At the time I last updated this page, these projects had found (but not stored) all the prime up to $10^{18}$, but not yet to $10^{19}$.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/Primes/Pix/results.html) and [this](http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/Primes/Pix/results.html) has $\pi(4\times 10^{22}) = 783,964,159,847,056,303,858$ as the record, from 2001 so it may be out of date.

As far as I can tell, the largest prime below $4\times 10^{22}$ is $39999999999999999999953$, though it would be easy enough to find the next ($40000000000000000000021$) and the next and the next...